# Navigation in app using speech recognition

Tags: objective-c, ios9, voice-recognition, siri

I will explain the scenario.I have a tableview with "A", "B","C","D", in its cells.On clicking cell with "A",app got navigate to a Viewcontroller  which will present a label with text "A" on it.So now my task is to implement voice recognition in this app.ie,If i say "A" app should navigate to the Viewcontroller and print "A".I know we have to use some Voice Recognition API for this.There are many API's present.So please suggest which one is best for using with iOS9

Answer (score 4):

**OpenEars** is best library for voice recognition.

Some of the features are

-> Perform speech recognition in English and in Spanish

-> Perform text-to-speech in English and with the NeatSpeech plugin, can also perform text-to-speech in Spanish

-> Listen continuously for speech on a background thread, while suspending or resuming speech processing on demand, all while using less than 2% CPU on average on current devices (decoding speech, text-to-speech, updating the UI and other intermittent functions use more CPU),

-> Use any of 9 voices for speech, including male and female voices with a range of speed/quality level, and switch between them on the fly,Change the pitch, speed and variance of any text-to-speech voice,

-> Know whether headphones are plugged in and continue voice recognition during text-to-speech only when they are plugged in,

-> Support bluetooth audio devices (experimental),

-> Be installed in a Cocoa-standard fashion using an easy-peasy already-compiled framework.

->In addition to its various new features and faster recognition/text-to-speech responsiveness, OpenEars™ now has improved recognition accuracy.

->OpenEars is free to use in an iPhone or iPad app.

for more information you can visit this link : [Link](http://www.politepix.com/openears/+voice+recognition+api+for+ios&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in)

Comment: your link is broken... do you meant [this link](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)?

Comment: will openears support iOS9?

Comment: Yes, OpenEars supportd iOS 9.

Comment: please appreciate answer if this helps you.. Thanks